# Unable to read anchor tab values neither in Status/ Envelope returned by https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

Tags: .net, docusignapi

Unable to read anchor tab values neither in Status/ Envelope returned by https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx 
We are using the above webservice as webreference in our .Net project to send agreements to customers to take signatures, some consents like 'I agree to this', 'Iagree to that' and then get that signed agreement back to us.

Methods we are using for getting Status:

- RequestStatus(TrimSafe(sEnvelopeID))
- RequestStatusWithDocumentFields(TrimSafe(sEnvelopeID))

Methods used for Envelope/Document:

- oDocSign.RequestStatus(TrimSafe(sEnvelopeID))
- oDocSign.RequestEnvelopeWithDocumentFields(sEnvelopeID, False)

This time our client wants us to read values from the anchortabs (if checkbox is selected, if radiobox is selected etc..) There is nothing in 'Value' Fields in response from any of above methods

Is there a different method I have to use to get the achor Tab values (Ex: the customer ticks on checkbox saying 'I agree'..  Now I need the value of that consent in my response in status, or envelope?)

Perhaps is there a different property i should look into?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the checkbox is checked on the test envelope you are querying?

When I do RequestEnvelopeWithDocumentFields against an envelope, a checked checkbox appears as a `<Tab>` element with `<value>X</value>`

Selected Radio Buttons have a value of `X` as well

Comment: Hello Drew, Thank you for responding, And yes, for sure the checkbox is checked, Are you sending the request to this API : https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx  or a different one?

Comment: Also is there any setting in your Docusign Account that you have turned on to get the values ??  Thanks in advance